# Calling specific page with wp query

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, custom-field

I'm making one page website and I added a custom field on "Page" post type that asks "Use this page as a section:" Yes or No(with dropdown). I called all pages on template-onepage.php(custom template) using wp query

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pages',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (the_query->have_posts()): the_query->the_posts ?>
    <?php some content here ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now what I want is to call only those page that set "Use this page as a section" to yes.. How can I achieve it ??? Please help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a meta query, which will specifically select those posts that have both the meta key you want, and the desired value.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pages',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'use-this-page-as-a-section', // or whatever the key is
        'value'   => 'yes'
     )
 );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: 'key' is the slug of the field? right?

Comment: Ok I got it now thanks for your help.. Thank you very much..

Comment: @Hussy571 yes, "key" is the slug of the field.